# Detect if there is gray color in image by opencv Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm new to cv2 library and I want to make a program that will detect if there is gray color in an image at real time.
Until now I took a code that will show me the screen in real time

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import pyautogui
from mss import mss
from PIL import Image

mon = {'top': 268, 'left': 968, 'width': 931, 'height': 599}

sct = mss()

while 1:
    sct.get_pixels(mon)
    img = Image.frombytes('RGB', (sct.width, sct.height), sct.image)
    cv2.imshow('test', np.array(img))
    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

But I have no idea how to detect if gray color appear in the screen(The other questions is about if all the picture is gray and not if gray appear in the screen)

Comment: do you have a specific, known gray value? you could look for rgb values that are within a few points from each other

Comment: @TenaciousB Yeah I know the specific gray value but How do I search the RGB values in the screen, thats what I dont know how to do

Comment: See cv2.inRange() for color thresholding. Threshold the image. Then count the number of white pixels or just check the mean value. If greater than 0, it has some white and thus the original has gray. See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga48af0ab51e36436c5d04340e036ce981. Then search this forum or Google for examples.

Comment: check my answer @avielovadiya

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The better way is to change the colour space into HSV and find the Hue value range for colour.

- Take each frame of the video
- Convert from BGR to HSV color-space
- Threshold the HSV image for a range of blue colour

Below code  is from [OpenCV official](https://docs.opencv.org/master/df/d9d/tutorial_py_colorspaces.html) site to detect the blue colour object

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)
while(1):
    # Take each frame
    _, frame = cap.read()
    # Convert BGR to HSV
    hsv = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    # define range of blue color in HSV
    lower_blue = np.array([110,50,50])
    upper_blue = np.array([130,255,255])
    # Threshold the HSV image to get only blue colors
    mask = cv.inRange(hsv, lower_blue, upper_blue)
    # Bitwise-AND mask and original image
    res = cv.bitwise_and(frame,frame, mask= mask)
    cv.imshow('frame',frame)
    cv.imshow('mask',mask)
    cv.imshow('res',res)
    k = cv.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

***For Live screen Gray colour Detection***

the range will be in HSV is

lower_blue = np.array([0,0,0])
upper_blue = np.array([255,10,255])

In HSV/HSL colourspace, the grey pixels are characterized by having a Saturation of very close to zero. Then the Value channel will tell you how far along the scale from black to white they actually are, low Lightness/Value is dark grey whereas high Lightness/Value means light grey.

So for the grey colour, your code is as below

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from mss import mss
import cv2 as cv
import cv2
mon = {'top': 268, 'left': 968, 'width': 931, 'height': 599}
sct = mss()
while (1):
  # Take each
  sct.get_pixels(mon)
  img = Image.frombytes('RGB', (sct.width, sct.height), sct.image)
  img = np.array(img)
  # Convert RGB to HSV
  hsv = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_RGB2HSV)
  # define range of gray color in HSV
  lower_gray = np.array([0, 0, 0])
  upper_gray = np.array([255, 10, 255])
  # Threshold the HSV image to get only gray colors
  mask = cv.inRange(hsv, lower_gray, upper_gray)
  # Bitwise-AND mask and original image
  res = cv.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)
  cv.imshow('original', img)
  cv.imshow('mask', mask)
  cv.imshow('res', res)
  k = cv.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
  if k == 27:
    break
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

The following code can be used for static images

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
image_path ="trail.jpg"
img = cv2.imread(image_path)
# Convert BGR to HSV
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
# define range of gray color in HSV
lower_gray = np.array([0,0,0])
upper_gray = np.array([255,10,255])
# Threshold the HSV image to get only gray colors
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_gray, upper_gray)
# Bitwise-AND mask and original image
res = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img, mask= mask)
cv2.imwrite("output.png",res)
```

Comment: Check the link + identify your gray colour range with cv2.trackbar

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but you send me code for detect gray in camera and I need it to the computer screen

Comment: @avielovadiya, do you need for an image that already captured

Comment: The last section that you added will fit to the Gray colour  detection code? that you added? Because I want to detect gray color in real time on screen not on just a one image

Comment: what do you mean by screen

Comment: I mean on screen video, Your solution is for camera video and I want to the screen video(Computer Screen Video, not Camera Video)

Comment: Hey, I think it will be good just one more thing. You used frame variable but there is no variable that called frame so the code not compiled